# Тире перед сравнительным оборотом с "как"

Tags: пунктуация, тире, союзы, сравнительный-оборот, обороты-с-как

"Она жалуется, что устает от работы. Это, наверно, блаженная **усталость – как у крестьянина** после дня работы в поле". Виктор Пелевин, "Священная книга оборотня".

Чем мотивирована постановка такого пунктуационного знака? Можно ли считать это авторской пунктуацией, на которую всегда можно списать ту или иную пунктуационную вольность?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Она жалуется, что **устает** от работы. Это, наверно, **блаженная** усталость **– как у крестьянина после дня работы в поле**. От такой усталости заживают душевные раны и забываются скорби...*

Выбор тире оправдан. Распространённый сравнительный оборот с ***как*** характеризует не столько саму ***усталость***, сколько её определение ***блаженная***. Именно это слово является смысловым центром и выделяется интонационно, так как в первом предложении уже есть информация об усталости.
Пауза перед оборотом более выраженная, тон понижается. На мой взгляд, запятая здесь совсем не подходит, она не покажет отношения частей. Сравнительный оборот имеет **пояснительный** характер. Пунктуация не противоречит правилам.

Можно ли считать это авторской пунктуацией? Скорее да, чем нет, поскольку в правилах, насколько мне известно, такой случай не описан. Есть, например, у Валгиной ([Союзные присоединительные конструкции](http://yanko.lib.ru/books/language/ru/yanko.valgina_2003_416p_rasp_sl.htm#_Toc331394012)):

> **3.** Присоединительное значение могут приобретать подчинительные союзы и союзные местоименно-наречные слова: *если, потому что, ибо, что, который, **как**, как (бы), когда* и др.
> Особенностью присоединительных конструкций с подчинительными союзами и союзными словами является то, что они приобретают характер присоединения лишь в результате отрыва от основного предложения, т. е. в результате парцелляции.
> Парцеллированными могут оказаться придаточные части предложения, **сравнительные и уточняющие обороты**.

Оборот в рассматриваемом предложении действительно напоминает присоединение. Можно было бы написать и с парцелляцией:
*Это, наверно, блаженная усталость. Как у крестьянина после дня работы в поле*.
Но автору, да и читателю, не нужно такое отделение. Даже если наш оборот является присоединительной конструкцией (а тире в этом случае – один из "правильных" знаков), всё же на первом плане мы видим его явное пояснительное значение.

Comment: Спасибо. Классное обоснование!

Comment: @ИванРоманов Спасибо, Иван, за интересный вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

**Пунктуационная вольность?** А  я представлю нашу пунктуационную и всякую другую **зажатость**. Нам во всем нужны правила...

**Примеряю** знаки.

(1) *Это, наверно, блаженная **устАлость**, / **как у крестьянина после дня работы в пОле**.*

Запятая? Нет, интонация совсем **не та...**

Я бы даже так прочитала: *Это, наверно, / **блажЕнная** усталость, /// **как у крестьянина / после дня работы в пОле.***

В первой части уже есть законченность, а потом пауза, размышление, оценка.

(2) Тогда **единый знак**?

*Это, наверно, блаженная усталость,  **— как у крестьянина после дня работы в пОле.***

Графика **непривычная**, не поймут...  Правда, и тире перед союзом КАК тоже выглядит непривычно.

(3) Но других вариантов нет, пусть уж будет **тире**.

*Это, наверно,  блажЕнная усталость —  **как у крестьянина после дня работы в поле.***

**P. S.**  Правила? А **правила** всегда найдутся, не в них дело...  Даже ссылаться  на авторскую пунктуацию  обычно не приходится.

Comment: Sharon, радостно, что мы сошлись в интонации и в выборе знака (хотя и выбора-то особо не видно).

Comment: Три слеша подряд? Это как? Только по одному или по два может ьыть. Ошибка или я чего-то не знаю?

Comment: @Sharon Вы знаете, мне ведь не зря пришла в голову мысль про пунктуационную вольность. Я вот разыскал и прочитал статью, которую приводит Розенталь в своём справочнике. Называется она "Пунктуация при сравнениях с союзам КАК в современных поэтических текстах" за авторством Некрасовой Е.А. Так вот, в ней автор отмечает абсолютную, ничем не ограниченную свободу пунктуационного оформления сравнительного оборота с союзом КАК современными поэтами. Оно, конечно, понятно, поэты - люди творческие, им можно ставить запятые так, как им нравится, и нести  это в  широкие массы.

Comment: @Sharon Но как быть нам, простым смертным, которые хотят разобраться в этом очень непростом вопросе, если уж светочи русской словесности не могут прийти к единому мнению, что считать художественным, фразеологическим сравнением, а что - общеязыковым. Так или иначе, но какой-то нормативности всё-таки бы хотелось.  С уважением.)

Comment: Надо избавиться от зажатости, Иван.  Запятая, тире или оба, как у нас здесь говорят...  Не много красок у художника слова. Но их все-таки достаточно. Слушайте разговорную речь —  она часто ярче и интереснее, чем книжная. Старайтесь все речевые оттенки выразить на письме — хорошая практика. Тогда и можно понять, что означает каждый знак. Познакомьтесь с ним поближе, и он будет вам другом, а не врагом. Я в каждом предложении вижу не только письменные знаки, но и  картинку-ситуацию.  Что-то вроде moving pictures — кто, когда и кому говорит.

Comment: Право на художественное сравнение?  Оно есть у всех «простых смертных», мы не хуже  наших творческих гениев. Нормативность?   Присоединительные конструкции подойдут?  Вы скажете: там тире при отсутствии союза.  Это обычно так,  но разве тире перед КАК  запрещено?  Вот хотя бы тире перед именным сказуемым: обычно не ставится, но по Лопатину «при акцентировании сказуемого (обычно в стилистических целях) тире возможно: Чернеющие прогалины — как черные острова… Здесь всего-то и надо, что ПОСЧИТАТЬ весь оборот присоединительной конструкцией,  а союз КАК  присоединительным союзом НЕ СЧИТАТЬ))

Comment: Мы вас редко видим, к сожалению. Вы не моли бы рассказать нам о моделях оформления оборотов по книге "Пунктуация при сравнениях с союзам КАК в современных поэтических текстах". Просто коротко обозначить некоторые. Это можно сделать в формате "вопрос — ответ".  И еще: Вы читаете Пелевина? И как вам эта книга?

Comment: @Sharon Я здесь и слежу за вашими ответами постоянно, так что не думайте, что меня здесь нет.) И да, вы знаете, я ничего не имею против игры пунктуационными знаками для придания высказыванию выразительности, как это делают мэтры слова, но всё же сперва хотелось бы усвоить нормативное написание, чтобы потом вкраплять туда какие-нибудь возможные переливчатые оттенки.)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149521/discussion-between---and-sharon).

Comment: Наверное, вы правы, сначала надо освоить базовые знания, нормативное написание и т.д. ... но я так не думаю.  Зачем повторять пройденный кем-то путь, лучше сразу идти дальше. А туда,  в начало ... можно просто заглядывать при необходимости.  К примеру, обсуждается какая-то тема.  Можно принять участие, и тогда будет понятно, что хорошо знаешь, а что не очень. То, что актуально в текущий момент, вызывает интерес, помогает понять  противоречия, нестыковки мнений.  Разные точки зрения позволяют видеть объемное изображение предмета. Или так: Different points of view allow you to see the truth.